# how to define a dynamic constructor in R for s4 object

Tags: r, r-s4

Is it possible to define a dynamic constructor in R for a S4 object? By dynamic I mean the following:

```
firstClass <- setClass(Class = "firstClass",slots = c(Name = "character", ID = "numeric"))
```

Now I would like to define a constructor which is smart, i.e. it checks what arguments where provided by the function call and creates a object of calss "firstClass" by setting the slots do default or the provided argument. For example

```
firstClass <- function(Name, ID){
  if(missing(Name) & missing(ID)){
    return(new(Class = firstClass))
  }
  if(missing(Name) & !missing(ID)){
    return(new(Class = firstClass,ID = ID))
  }
  if(!missing(Name) & missing(ID)){
    return(new(Class,Name = Name))
  }
  if(!missing(Name) & !missing(ID)){
    return(new(Class, Name = Name, ID = ID))
  }
}
```

Clearly some sanity checks should be done as well. This constructor does exactly what I want, depending of the call it constructs an object. However, for an simple class (few slots) this is ok, but with more slots the complexity grows. So I'm wondering if there is an elegant way to do it.

Comment: Have you tried running the default `firstClass()` with a varying no. of arguments? It already does what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Use a prototype to provide sane default values

```
.firstClass <-
    setClass(Class = "firstClass",
             representation = representation(
               Name = "character",
               ID = "integer"),
             prototype=c(ID=0L))
```

Use default values as arguments in the constructor, as well as coercion to appropriate types if necessary

```
firstClass <- function(Name=character(), ID=0L)
    .firstClass(Name=Name, ID=as.integer(ID))
```

(`.firstClass` is a light wrapper around `new("firstClass", ...)`, to me it provides a little separation between the implementation details (calling new() to construct a class) and the interface to class construction. `firstClass()` is a second and more useful layer, explosing necessary arguments for object construction to the user in a way that does not require knowledge of the underlying class). Enforce 'sanity checks' in a validity method

```
setValidity("firstClass", function(object) {
    msg <- NULL
    if (length(object@ID) != 1)
        msg <- c(msg, "ID must be length 1")
    else if (object@ID < 0)
        msg <- c(msg, "ID must be >= 0")
    if (is.null(msg)) TRUE else msg
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm new to s4 in R, so what is the benefit of having two different functions: .firstClass and firstClass?

Comment: @user8 some comments added to the text

Comment: Thanks for the additional comments. Why then not just writing: `firstClass <- function(Name = character(), ID=0L){return(new("firstClass",Name = Name, ID = ID))}`.